# Перемещение чисел в массиве

Tags: c++

> В одномерном массиве все отрицательные числа переместить в начало массива, а остальные в конец с сохранением порядка следования. Дополнительный массив заводить не разрешается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Предложу некоторые альтернативы, вдруг будет интересно:**

```
#include <algorithm>
int array[64];
// Каким-то образом заполняем массив.
std::sort(array, array + 64);
```

---

**Для случая `C++0x`:**

```
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
```

**Для случая не-`C++0x`, если хочется иметь аналоги `std::begin` и `std::end`:**

```
template<class Cont> typename Cont::iterator begin(Cont& c){
    return c.begin();
}

template<class Cont> typename Cont::iterator end(Cont& c){
  return c.end();
}

template<class Cont> typename Cont::const_iterator begin(Cont const& c){
  return c.begin();
}

template<class Cont> typename Cont::const_iterator end(Cont const& c){
  return c.end();
}

// Версии для C-style массивов.
template<class T, std::size_t N> T* begin(T (&arr)[N]){
    return &arr[0];
}

template<class T, std::size_t N> T* end(T (&arr)[N]){
    return arr + N;
}

// Используются наши локально определенные функции.
std::sort(begin(array), end(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void sort(int *a,int razmer)
{
    for(int i=0;i<razmer-1;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<razmer-1-i;j++)
            if(a[j]>0)
                if(a[j+1]<0)
                {
                    int temp;
                    temp=a[j];
                    a[j]=a[j+1];
                    a[j+1]=temp;
                }
}
```